# how do I access arcadedb in k8s mode？

Tags: arcadedb

I have install a arcadedb cluster in k8s mode，
when I visit it in remote client，it will return a k8s
leader adress, which I can't recognize the adress in remote client。

Resulted in I can't visit the arcadedb cluster.

The arcadedb version is 24.2.1.

Comment: when visit different node in cluster，can get different info

Comment: Have you already checked the docs? https://docs.arcadedb.com/#_troubleshooting-2

Comment: i have read，when i visit it in my JavaAPI，it return the server adress which is the pod adress，and the JavaAPI outside k8s can't recognize.